# Url rewrite must start with and not ends with

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want a rewrite rule which checks a url. It should start with a condition and should not have an extention.

This is the rule I created for so far:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/?(.*)$ admin/index.php?rt=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]
```

I have a second rule which is applied to everything with extention .html. So I want that if for some reason i do this: http://domain.com/admin/page-to-test.html should be applied to the second rule and not match with the first one.
I have tried with also:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/?(.*)(!\.html)$ admin/index.php?rt=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]
```

However that didn't work either. It should start with admin (optional slash) and not have a extension.

Edit: I changed the RewriteRules and that works. So when the Rule match, it stops because of the L.
Else it tries to find a other rule which works. If not put the L beyond the rule, all rules will be checked and can give a problem.

So total:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ index.php?rt=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^admin/?(.*)$ admin/index.php?rt=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Are there any other rules beside ".html" rule and "admin" rule?  Could you please show us your ".html" rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your ".html" rule before "admin" rule and mark ".html" rule with "L" flag, so no rules will be applied after it.